# Android End (Waiting Call) programatically

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager, incoming-call

I'm building some sort of util app for Call Center people. Where I've to perform action on waiting call.

Suppose ABC tries to call me and I answered call, and same time XYZ also tries to call me then XYZ call will moved to waiting state untill I make some dicision like end call with ABC or reject XYZ call.

Till now I'm able to detect when ABC is talking with me and XYZ calls me- I'm getting the event for the same. when in that event case if i call/run disconnectCall method then my first call is getting endup but I want to end second call automatically instead of first one.

Check out my code below which detect waiting call too **onNewIncomingCallReceived** this log is added when new call is placed into waiting.

```
public class CallListenerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

//The receiver will be recreated whenever android feels like it.  We need a static variable to remember data between instantiations
private static int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
private static Date callStartTime;
private static boolean isIncoming;
private boolean isUserOnCall = false;
private static final String TAG = "CallListenerReceiver";
private static String savedNumber;  //because the passed incoming is only valid in ringing

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    //We listen to two intents.  The new outgoing call only tells us of an outgoing call.  We use it to get the number.
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
        savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
    } else {
        String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        int state = 0;
        if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
        } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
        } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
        }

        onCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
    }
}

//Incoming call-  goes from IDLE to RINGING when it rings, to OFFHOOK when it's answered, to IDLE when its hung up
//Outgoing call-  goes from IDLE to OFFHOOK when it dials out, to IDLE when hung up

public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String number) {
    if (lastState == state) return;
    switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            isIncoming = true;
            callStartTime = new Date();
            savedNumber = number;

            if (lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                showToast(context, "New Call In Waiting");
                Log.d(TAG, "onNewIncomingCallReceived : ");
                disconnectCall(context);
            } else {
                showToast(context, "Call Received");
                Log.d(TAG, "onIncomingCallReceived : ");
            }
            break;

        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            //Transition of ringing-> offhook are pickups of incoming calls.  Nothing done on them
            if (lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                isIncoming = false;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                Log.d(TAG, "onOutgoingCallStarted : ");
            } else {
                isUserOnCall = true;
                isIncoming = true;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                showToast(context, "Call Answered");
                Log.d(TAG, "onIncomingCallAnswered : ");
            }
            break;

        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            //Went to idle-  this is the end of a call.  What type depends on previous state(s)
            if (lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                //Ring but no pickup-  a miss
                showToast(context, "onMissedCall");
                Log.d(TAG, "onMissedCall : ");
            } else if (isIncoming) {
                isUserOnCall = false;
                showToast(context, "onIncomingCallEnded");
                Log.d(TAG, "onIncomingCallEnded : ");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "onOutgoingCallEnded : ");
            }
            break;
    }
    lastState = state;
}

private void disconnectCall(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        try {
            TelecomManager telecomManager = (TelecomManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);
            if (telecomManager != null)
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    telecomManager.endCall();
                else
                    showToast(context, "Permission not available to disconnect call");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                if (tm == null) return;
                tm.getClass().getMethod("endCall").invoke(tm);
            } catch (Exception se) {
            }
        }
    } else endCall(context);
}

private void endCall(Context context) {
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    try {
        Method m = tm.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony telephonyService = (com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
        telephonyService.endCall();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void showToast(Context context, String toastMessage) {
    Toast.makeText(context, toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

Can anyone help me with to end the second call automatically then user user is already talking with someone else. I'm finding solution for this last 3 days but I didn't get it.